# Check AWS cli version on bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, variables, scripting

I am creating a script to check AWS Cli version and store it in a Variable to use it later.

```
#!/bin/bash

OS=$(uname -a)
AWS_CLI=$(aws --version)

echo echo "{\"changed\":false,\"kernal version\":\"$OS\",\"AWS CLI version\":\"$AWS_CLI\"}"
```

But the output is shown as following.

```
{
    "AWS CLI version": "",     
    "kernal version": "Linux ip-10-0-14-174 ... x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux"
}
```

How can I get the value of aws --version to bash variable?

Comment: You haven't used $AWS_CLI anywhere?

Comment: @RamanSailopal, sorry. I have updated the script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my Centos 7, I need to pick the stderr:

```
AWS_CLI_VERSION=$(aws --version 2>&1 | cut -d " " -f1 | cut -d "/" -f2)
```